Load specific image in ucrop instead of gallery selection
I am trying to write an android app for timer management. It runs an OCR on an image from the gallery. I would like to be able to crop it first. I am trying to load a specific image in Yalantis ucrop instead of selecting from the gallery. I have already selected the image to use so I can get other info from it. The following code works but I can't get the other needed info from the image and the resulting uri won't give me what I need because it's modified after. How can I use a known Uri or bitmap instead of calling "image/" in the line mGetContent.launch("image/");?
    ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent=registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), result -> {
            Intent intent= new Intent(this, CropperActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("DATA", result.toString());
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
        });

        mGetContent.launch("image/*");

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.v("onActivityResult", "requestCode: " + requestCode);
        Log.v("onActivityResult", "resultCode: " + resultCode);

        if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == -1 && data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            imgCap.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            //getOCR(selectedImage.toString());
        } else {
            Log.e("capture error", "error: no image!!!!!!!");
        }
    }



CropperActivity
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.yalantis.ucrop.UCrop;
import com.yalantis.ucrop.model.AspectRatio;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CropperActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String result;
    Uri fileUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.v_cropper);

        readIntent();

        String dest_uri= UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg";

        UCrop.Options options=new UCrop.Options();
        options.setAspectRatioOptions(3,
                new AspectRatio("1:1", 1, 1),
                new AspectRatio("2:1", 2, 1),
                new AspectRatio("3:1", 3, 1),
                new AspectRatio("5:1", 5, 1),
                new AspectRatio("8:1", 8, 1),
                new AspectRatio("10:1", 10, 1));

        UCrop.of(fileUri, Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(),dest_uri)))
                .withOptions(options)
                .withMaxResultSize(2000,2000)
                .start(CropperActivity.this);

    }

    private void readIntent() {
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
            result=intent.getStringExtra("DATA");
            fileUri=Uri.parse(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==UCrop.REQUEST_CROP){
            final Uri resultURI=UCrop.getOutput(data);
            Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("RESULT", String.valueOf(resultURI));
            setResult(-1, returnIntent);
            finish();
        } else if(resultCode==UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
            final Throwable cropError=UCrop.getError(data);
        }
    }
}

